# How to allow users to connect their own domain

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I am creating am online service that creates a public profile pages for the members of different organizations. I want to have the organizations attach a domain (likely a subdomain of their main url), but I'm not sure how to set this up through PHP.

An example of what I'm looking for would be how Tumblr lets you connect your own domain:

[image]

So what I would like is for **profile.useraddedurl.com/XYZ** to display **appurl.com/user.php?domain=profile.useraddedurl.com&id=XYZ**

I would like to know the best way to set this up in PHP, and if any special server configurations need to be put in place.

I think I may need to dynamically create a htaccess file, but is there a better way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to let the user set up their personal domain.

It is up to them to point it at the right IP address (which you'll probably want them to use a CNAME record for), but you'll need to give them the information they need to do that.

You will also need to provide a form so they can tell you what domain name they want you to handle for them. Store this in you database.

Then you need to show the right site when you get a request.

The general approach is to ensure that all requests are handled by the same script (use the front controller pattern).

If you want to use Virtual Name Hosting to handle specific domains with a different script (e.g. `api.example.com`) then make sure the *default* one (the one defined first if you are using Apache) is this one. If you don't want to do that, then avoid Virtual Name Hosting entirely as it just creates complications.

Then, in the PHP script, look at `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`. Compare that to the registered domains in the database. If you get a match, show that user's site. Otherwise, show your default.

Comment: Will the user domains need to be added as aliases on my server? Or will this need to be setup on a VPS  rather than on a shared host?

Comment: "Will the user domains need to be added as aliases on my server?" — That depends on what you mean by "aliases". The [Apache alias directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#alias) is for paths not hostnames. I already described what was needed as far as DNS or virtual name hosting in the answer.

Comment: "will this need to be set up on a VPS rather than on a shared host?" — On a shared host you will not have the access required to be able to make your site the default one as described in the penultimate paragraph of the answer.